# Oaxaca Decomposition How to Interpret Percentage higher than 100%

Tags: regression, econometrics

I have trouble understanding the interpretation and calculation of the "percentage explained" in the Oaxaca decomposition.

Both the Stata and R packages don't automatically report them, so I am wondering if I am doing it correctly.

I am using the [World Bank equation](http://siteresources.worldbank.org/INTPAH/Resources/Publications/459843-1195594469249/HealthEquityCh12.pdf). They simply calculate the `% explained` with explained divided by total gap.

This is the result of a simple twofold Oaxaca decomposition.

```
GroupRep       45.6
Group1         50.31
TotalGap       -4.713

Endowment      5.519
Unexplained    -10.232
```

So, here you can see that both the Endowment and Unexplained are larger than the total gap.

The percentage explained should then be `(5.519/-4.713)*100 = -117.1%` and 
`(-10.232/-4.713)*100 = 217.1%`.

What do these percentages exactly mean?

I understand that I can interpret the Endowment part as, "if people in group 1 had the same characteristics as people in the ref group, they would have 5.519 more (whatever quantity we are measuring)". But I don't really get how to interpret the `-117.1%` explained.

Any clue?